# Scala: Partially applied functions

Tags: scala

I am relatively new to Scala, and just trying to get my head around the use of partially applied functions to solve my problem.

My problem is that in my code I have the following foreach logic in multiple places:

```
for (teamType <- TeamType.allTypes) {
  findViewById(teamType.layoutID).findViewById(buttonID)
    .setOnClickListener(matchButtonOnClickListener)
}
```

and again here:

```
for (teamType <- TeamType.allTypes) refreshTeamStatisticViews(teamType)
```

Basically, for each teamType in the TeamType case object, I am looking to perform a function that returns Unit

What I was thinking of doing is moving the foreach part into the TeamType case object, and then have that take a function or partially applied function that returns Unit.

So for example, TeamType would contain the following:

```
def forAllTeamTypes(fun: TeamType => Unit) = for(teamType <- allTypes) fun(teamType)
```

and for the second example above, I could change it to

```
TeamType.forAllTeamTypes(refreshTeamStatisticViews)
```

However, I am not sure how to apply this for partially applied functions for the more complex first example.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:

```
TeamType.forAllTeamTypes{ teamType =>
  findViewById(teamType.layoutID).findViewById(buttonID).setOnClickListener(matchButtonOnClickListener)
}
```

Let's look at your code:

```
for (teamType <- TeamType.allTypes) {
  findViewById(teamType.layoutID).findViewById(buttonID).setOnClickListener(matchButtonOnClickListener)
}
```

it [actually means](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/for-expressions-revisited.html) this:

```
TeamType.allTypes.foreach{ teamType =>
  findViewById(teamType.layoutID).findViewById(buttonID).setOnClickListener(matchButtonOnClickListener)
}
```

`foreach` method takes `TeamType => Unit` as parameter, just like your method `forAllTeamTypes`.

Answer (score 1):

You would probably be better off using the built in functions. It would seem like `.foreach` already has the signature you want.

It will look something like:

```
TeamType.allTypes.foreach (functionOfYourChoosing)
```

Comment: My TeamType is actually a case object, and not an enum. I should have clarified this

Comment: In there you could define a member `allTypes` that was a List[TeamType] ?  Or something. It's hard to judge without a more minimal and complete example :D